# SQL/Postgres group by and count with fallback?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have a table `things` with 3 columns, `id`, `animal` and `color`. For each row `animal` always has a value and `color` sometimes has a value. I need to count how many of each `color`, and for those rows without `color`, how many of each `animal`. Is this possible with one query? Would look like:

```
  things  
   id  | animal  |  color  |
    1     dog         black
    2     cat         black
    3     dog          null
    4     cat          null
```

I would want to get back essentially: `black: 2, cat: 1 and dog: 1`

Comment: To confirm, you want results in a single cell to include colons, commas and the word "and" if there are more than one animal or color in your results?

Comment: You may use two sub-queries in one query to get counts separately.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into sub-queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a UNION.

I would advise adding a literal column which specifies which result set it is.   This way, you can see what came from where.

You can just delete the ThingType columns if you don't need them.

```
SELECT 
   -- My addition - delete if not wanted
   'ByColor' as ThingType,
   color as ThingCounted,
   COUNT(DISTINCT animal) AS ThingCount
FROM
   things
GROUP BY
  color
UNION
SELECT 
   -- My addition - delete if not wanted
   'ByAnimal' as ThingType,
   animal as ThingCounted,
   COUNT(DISTINCT color) AS ThingCount
FROM
   things
GROUP BY
   animal
```

Comment: Using a union worked perfect, thanks!